# CAS 4.1 externalize configuration

Tags: java, spring, cas

I am configuring our branch of jasig CAS 4.1 with LDAP authentication. My deployerConfigContext.xml seems to work, I can connect correctly in the test environment.

I will be however deploying the .war file on multiple environments, each requiring different ldap url, domain name etc. These are out of the box defined in cas.properties file which is packed inside the war - managing that would quickly become unfeasable.

Is there a way to externalize LDAP configuration - to, say, ini file? Specifically for the following beans:

- `SearchEntryResolver` which requires `basedn`,
- `FormatDnResolver` requiring ldap domain,
- `ConnectionConfig` which uses ldap url

I know I can extend existing beans, and add my own code to read those values from wherever I like, however doing so to three separate beans for just that purpose seems... wastefull.